# Need help in understanding basic Assembly code which was generated from C code

Tags: c, assembly

I am learning Assembly and I am tring to understand how Assembly is being generated from C code.

I created following dummy C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int x, int y){
    int result = x + y;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int x = 1 * 10;
    int y = 2 * 5;
    int firstArg = x + y;
    int secondArg = firstArg / 2;
    int value;
    value = add(firstArg, secondArg);
    return value;
}
```

And got following Assembly code

```
.file   "first.c"
    .text
    .globl  add
    .type   add, @function
add:
.LFB39:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    8(%esp), %eax
    addl    4(%esp), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE39:
    .size   add, .-add
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB40:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $30, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE40:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

And I was very surprised where are all those arithmetic operations in main vanished?
I do not understand how we got $30 from a nowhere (well, I suppose it is a return value from add function, but why I do not see any command that gets this value, actually I see that return value was already pushed to eax in the add function, so why would we need to move $30 to eax again?). 
Where are all local main vars are being declared? I specially created 5 of them to see how one is pushed onto the stack.

Can you also help me to understand what are all those .LFE39 .LFB40: .LFB39: mean?

I am ready the book, but it does not clarify this case for me. 
Actually book says that all function must begin with stack initialization:

```
  pushl   %ebp
  movl    %esp, %ebp
```

As well as when function ends it needs to complete it with pop instruction.

Which is not the case in the above code. I do not see any stack initialization.

Thank you!

Comment: turn OFF the optimization feature of the compiler.  Then you will see all the code that has been optimized out of existence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are compiling with optimizations enabled. GCC was smart enough to perform all of those calculations at compile-time, and replace all of that useless code with a simple constant.

First of all, `x` and `y` will get replaced with their constant expressions:

```
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
```

Then, the places where those variables are used will instead get their constant values:

```
    int firstArg = 20;
    int secondArg = 10;
```

Next, your `add` function is small and trivial, so it will certainly get inlined:

```
    value = firstArg + secondArg;
```

Now those are constants too, so the whole thing will be replaced with:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 30;
}
```

---

While most functions will have a prologue like you've shown, your program does *nothing* but return 30. More specifically, it no longer uses any local variables, and calls no other functions.  Because of this `main` does not need a frame or reserved space on the call stack. So there's no need for the compiler to emit a prologue/epilogue.

```
main:
    movl    $30, %eax
    ret
```

These are the only two instructions your program will run (other than the C-runtime startup code).

---

Further note, that because your `add` function was not marked `static`, the compiler had to assume that someone externally might call it. For that reason, we still see `add` in the generated assembly, even though no one is calling it:

```
add:
    movl    8(%esp), %eax
    addl    4(%esp), %eax
    ret
```

Comment: oh, thanks, damn book just say to run 
gcc -O1 -S code.c

Comment: @FemX Yep, try `gcc -O0 -S` to disable optimizations.